# Разные результаты сортирвки по векторам

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка, векторы

Задача: отсортировать точки по осям в 3d-пространстве так, чтобы сортировка по текущей оси сохраняла порядок сортировки по предыдущей. Последовательность элементов в результирующем списке должна быть такой, как если бы мы обходили трехмерный массив с помощью трех вложенных циклов.

И вот тут я не совсем понимаю, что происходит. Если использовать OrderBy (быстрая сортировка), то всё работает как надо (порядок по предыдущим осям сохраняется), но если использовать, например, сортировку выбором, то порядок ломается. Вопрос: в такой задаче результат сортировки зависит от выбранного алгоритма или я чего-то не понимаю?

Исходный код: https://pastebin.com/9ZUTJLjd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировка выбором не является [устойчивой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), т.е. она может поменять порядок элементов с одинаковыми ключами.

К устойчивым относятся, например, сортировка вставками или сортировка слиянием, а вот quicksort - нет (имеются в виду обычные реализации).

Про OrderBy отмечено [в описании](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)

> Этот метод выполняет стабильную сортировку; то есть, если ключи двух
>   элементов равны, порядок элементов сохраняется. Напротив, нестабильная
>   сортировка не сохраняет порядок элементов с одинаковым ключом.

Кроме того, можно использовать сортировку с компаратором по составному ключу

```
если ключ верхнего уровня меньше, вернуть -1
если больше, вернуть +1
иначе перейти к сравнению ключей второго уровня и т.д.
```